# Shutdown computer via e-mail

Tags: shutdown, email, remote

Do you have a idea how to shutdown my ubuntu via e-mail?

For example
I send specific e-mail from my @gmail what cause my ubuntu shutdown.

Comment: There is no standard way to do this, because it is a massive security hole. You should not do it. Why would you want to do this? There are much better ways to do remote management than that.

Comment: Instead of email  use "ssh" .

Comment: You could make some script. But i dont know the benefits of using this trough send a email. As said use ssh instead.

Comment: I agree with users above: install an ssh server on your system, ssh client on phone and a one-liner to connect and shutdown.

Comment: I have Synology and I do backup of Synology using "Hyper Backup" to my Ubuntu. I want to shutdown my computer when backup finished. I get e-mail from Synology when backup is complete. I have idea to use this e-mail to shutdown my Ubuntu. 

Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 1):

**For example make a script in python :**

```
import os
os.system("shutdown now -h")
```

**The second is to configure /etc/sudoers so that user can run that script as root without needing a password:**

So if your mail user is a member of the group 'mailgroup' and the shutdown script is mailshutdown.py
in /usr/local/sbin, then your entry in sudoers would look something like this:

```
%mailgroup   ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/mailshutdown
```